# How to access the value of an input in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I don't know how to access the value of the input, I've searched all over https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/ and haven't found an answer. Here is my TextField `

```
<TextField
  id="outlined-search"
  label="Поиск по названию"
  variant="outlined"
  onInput={console.log('Input FIRE')}
/>
```

onInput doesn't work yet.

I don’t remember what I tried, my ass is on fire.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check this event, it could be helpful

```
onInput={e => console.log('Input FIRE>>', e)}
```

you can try to check this one `e.target.value` or something different.

Comment: `e.target.value` is not there. I don't know why this was accepted as  the answer unless the OP wanted to just print something in the console.